# Proving that if $n>2$ then $n!>n^{n/2}$ using induction.

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

How to prove that if $n>2$ then $n!>n^{n/2}$ using induction?

Comment: Did you try the base case? Where are you struggling in the inductive case? :-)

Comment: I get (k+1)!>k^(k/2)*(k+1) and don't know what I can do then.

Comment: Try going backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$\left(n+1\right)!=n!\left(n+1\right)>n^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(n+1\right)$.

So it is enough to prove that: $$n^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(n+1\right)\geq\left(n+1\right)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$$
or equivalently: $$n+1\geq\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}$$ This for $n>2$.

Comment: How do you get  n+1≥(1+1/n)^n

Comment: 1) on both sides take the square. 2) on both sides divide by $n+1$.
3) on both sides divide by $n^{n}$

Comment: @Sona You need $n^{n/2}\geq (n+1)^{(n-1)/2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I'm at my first year at university and couldn't do my homework.

Comment: You are very welcome. Persevere and good luck with your study.