Prove using mathematical induction that the given inequality holds for all n>2.
The inequality is: $$n! > n^{\frac{n}{2}}$$
This is what I've tried:
$n=3 \Rightarrow 6>3^{\frac32}\\$
Assume the inequality holds for some $k\in\Bbb{N}: k! > k^{\frac{k}{2}}$
Prove the inequality holds for $(k+1)! > (k+1)^{\frac{k+1}{2}}$
Then:
$\begin{align*}
(k+1)! &> (k+1)^{\frac{k+1}{2}} \\
(k+1) \cdot k! &> (k+1)^{\frac{k+1}{2}} \\
\end{align*}$
Now using the inductive hypothesis:
$\begin{align*}
k! &> k^{\frac{k}{2}} \\
(k+1) \cdot k! &> (k+1) \cdot k^{\frac{k}{2}}
\end{align*}
$
We get:
$\begin{align*}(k+1) \cdot k^{\frac{k}{2}} &> (k+1)^{\frac{k+1}{2}}
\end{align*}
$
And this is where I got to. Any help is appreciated.

If you are trying to prove that something holds for $n\gt 2$ then the base case is $n=3$. In fact, $1!=\sqrt{1}$ so the inequality doesn't hold for $n=1$.

$3$ is not greater than $3^\frac{3}{2}$

Start with $n=3$ : $3^{3\over2} =3\sqrt{3} < 3\sqrt{4} = 3\times 2 =6! $

This question is similar to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640602/show-that-if-n2-then-n2nn – If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923990/proving-that-if-n2-then-nnn-2-using-induction and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339036/how-to-prove-this-inequality-with-factorials-nn-frac-n2 and probably many more.

Try
if $n>2$ let $1\le k \le n-1$ then either $k$ or $n+1-k$ is $\ge n$. So $k(n+1-k) \ge n$
taking product we get $(n-1)!n! \ge n^{n-1}$ so $n!^2 \ge n^{n}$ thus $n! > n^{n/2}$

How can k<=n-1 and >= n? and n+1-k>=n only if k<=1. It's true that k(n+1-k)>=n and >n if k>1 but your proof of that doesn't work. What are you taking the product of to get the (n-1)! and how did >= turn into > at the end?

The problem is simplified by taking logarithms. For $n!$ we have from Stirling's approximation:
$$ \ln n! > n \ln n - n $$
Therefore if we can show:
$$ n \ln n - n > \frac{n}{2} \ln n $$
Or:
$$ \ln n > 2 $$
then we're done. We can show it holds for n > 8 so for $n > 8$ we conclude $n! > n^{\frac{n}{2}}$. The remaining $2 < n < 8$ can be verified separately.

Assume $n>2$
$$n!=\prod_1^ni$$
For even $n>2$, say $n=2m$
$$n!=\prod_1^mi\prod_1^m(n+1-i)=\prod_1^mi(n+1-i)$$
and for odd $n$, say $n=2m+1$
$$n!=(m+1)\prod_1^mi(n+1-i)$$
Let $f(i)=i(n+1-i)$, then
$$df/di=n+1-2i$$
which is positive for $i\in [1,(n+1)/2)$ hence for $i\in [1,m]$.
When $i=1$, $f(i)=n$, so $f(i)>n$ for $i\in (1,m]$.
Hence $$\prod_1^mf(i)=\prod_1^mi(n+1-i)>n^m\text{ if }m>1$$
That is the required result for even $n$.
For odd $n$ we need to show $m+1>\sqrt n$
From a.m$\geqslant$g.m.
$$(m+1)/2\geqslant\sqrt m$$
$$m+1\geqslant\sqrt{4m}>\sqrt{2m+1}\text{ since }m\geqslant 1$$
And that completes the required result for odd $n$.
Of course, there's not much mathematical induction apparent, but then you can always show $\phi(n)\Rightarrow\phi(n+1)$ if you can show $\phi(n+1)$.
